# What is the standard layout for a three-column List Component in Android?

Tags: android, listview, components

I'm trying to put together a view in an Android application that has an Image, two text views within a Linear Layout, and another image. It is styled like a list view 'cell', and let me to wonder what the best way to create the Android standard List item component is.  The style guide for Android is very specific when talking about how these components should look, but there aren't many development guidelines on reproducing those components consistently.

For example, I'm essentially trying to recreate this cell: 
[image]

Is there any standard layout for these cells?  If not, what would you say is the best way to handle this cell layout?

Currently the issue I'm having is that doing this kind of thing:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Never shows the second Image view.

Suggestions?  Either on my specific situation or on the standard layouts?

**Update**

I got my view working.  It was `LinearLayout` weights as someone suggested.  In the end to get it to work I had the two `ImageView`s with a weight of 1, and the internal `LinearLayout` with a weight of 0.

Sorry if this is a long question on a beginner topic - leaving it up for the more general part of the question - a standard layout for the standard Components.  (Maybe a candidate for Stack Overflow's new Documentation section.)

Comment: *Never shows the second ImageView* - And why not? Do you have the weight sums set incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Google didn't really go through and make standard layouts for many of these Material Design specs.

Here's a layout based on the spec to get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="88dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_error_white_24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
        tools:text="This is the title line"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
        tools:text="This is the second line"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
        tools:text="This is the third line"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_2"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_error_white_24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I didn't use dimension values and text styles; that is something you can go through and do.  This is just to get you on the right track.